# View file created but can't link to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I created this file: views/lendings/**terms.html.erb**

lendings controller works fine for the other views.

I just want to write a link from views/lendings/show to terms.html.erb view

Do i have to write an action in lendings controller just to do that?

How do I configure the routes file?
How do I create the link in show view?

```
<%= link_to 'read terms', lendings_terms_path %>  ?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you need to create an action called `terms` inside `LendingsController`. If you don't need anything special in the view, then you can just leave the method empty. Then in the routes file add this:

```
resources :lendings do
  collection do
    get :terms
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting this error in show.html.erb: undefined local variable or method `lending_terms_path' when I try: <%= link_to 'read terms', lending_terms_path %>

Comment: Try running `rake routes | grep terms` and see the name of the route (first column). To that name, add `_path` to the end and you will have the name of the helper method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it didn't work

```
resources :lendings do
  collection do
    get :terms
  end
end
```

Then it worked with:

```
resources :lendings do
  member do
    get 'terms' 
  end
end
```

As explained in: Adding More RESTful Actions/2.10.1 Adding Member Routes.
Check: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html